# AngularJS interceptor not returning on success

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add a popup with retry option as follows so that the user can click on that when lose the connection during a HTTP call.

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('httpResponseErrorInterceptor', ['$injector', '$q', function($injector, $q) {
  return {
        'responseError': function(response) { 
            var $ionicPopup = $injector.get('$ionicPopup');
            if (response.status === 0) {
                   var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                       title: 'No Connectivity!',
                       template: 'Internet not available'
                   });

                   confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
                        if(res) {
                            var $http = $injector.get('$http');
                            return $http(response.config);
                        } else {
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }
                   });
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

It is receiving the response from the http call, but not returning the response to the calling point. In the same way I tried the following code,

```
.factory('httpResponseErrorInterceptor', ['$injector', '$q', function($injector, $q) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(response) {
      if (response.status === 0) {
        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
        return $http(response.config);
      }
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}])
```

But this one is returning the response properly to the calling point when we get the connection back. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in the first code.

Any help/idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return confirmPopup.then() call.

Do like this:

```
return confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
    if(res) {
        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
        return $http(response.config);
    } else {
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
});
```

Example of chaining:

```
var promise = confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
    if(res) {
        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
        return $http(response.config);
    } else {
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
});


promise.then(function(success){
    //HTTP SUCCESS
}, function(error){
    //HTTP ERROR OR REJECT RESPONSE
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution and it works. Just for a clarification, is it not necessary to use `defer` and `resolve`?

Comment: No need. This return is just used for chaining promises. A good reference is https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q - "Chaining promises"

Comment: are you sure that this works? for me it looks like you're returning the confirm popup promise instead of the http promise which would result in wrong parameters passed to your outer callback (the one of the caller).
it should get passed the "res" value instead of "response.config"

Comment: Yes, I am returning the confirm popup promise, that has a callback that returns the $http promise or $q.reject(response);
This is the chaining principle of promise.

Comment: I improved my answer with an example!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Patrick Kelleter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754677/patrick-kelleter)'s answer, I framed this working solution,

```
.factory('httpResponseErrorInterceptor', ['$injector', '$q', function($injector, $q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(response) { 
            var $ionicPopup = $injector.get('$ionicPopup');
            var $ionicLoading = $injector.get('$ionicLoading');
            $ionicLoading.hide();

            if (response.status === 0) {
                var userInputDefer = $q.defer();                
                var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: 'No Connectivity!',
                    template: 'Internet not available',
                    okText: 'Retry'
                });

                confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
                    if(res) {
                        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
                        userInputDefer.resolve($http(response.config));
                    } else {
                        userInputDefer.reject($q.reject(response));
                    }
                });

                return userInputDefer.promise;
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Edit:**

Just for future reference for someone, for using the above HTTP interceptor, you have to include the factory in config as follows,

```
.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpResponseErrorInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: that's pretty much what i was heading to, yeah. glad you found a working solution based on my hint. however watch for my comment on the answer you marked as "correct" - i'm not sure if that one really was what you were looking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
                        if(res) {
                            var $http = $injector.get('$http');
                            return $http(response.config);
                        } else {
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }
                   });
```

here is the problem. you are returning stuff ($http / $q) in the asynchronous callback of the confirmPopup.
the confirmPopup is async and you define a callback via ".then".
whatever you are returning there will not reach your calling point. it is the return value of the callback. which probably will not land anywhere (depending on the implementation of confirmPopup, but i doubt that it expects you to return anything there)

you will have to use your own promise and return it *synchronously* at the end of your callback